# BackboneJS and Model/Collection

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

Have json-data like this:

```
{ tournaments: [ {
   tournament_id: "..."
   tournament_name: "..."
   events: [ {
       event_id: ...
       event_name: ....
       param : [ {
           param_a : 
           param_b : ..
           subparan : [ {
               sub_1: 1
               sub_2 : 2...
```

So. I don't understand - how to it implement into BackBone Collection/Model style?

How to handle change sub_1? - Made Collection of Collection of Collection?

Answer (score 3):

Simpliest way [described](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) in backbone tutorial:

```
var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.params = new Params() 
    }
})

var Tournaments = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.events = new Events()
    }
})
var tournaments = new Tournaments()
```

You can continue nesting by you needs. When I was working on similar task I wrap each collection in model representing collection state and change itself in answer of collection events. This allows not to asking nested collections about its state having actual state in model.

```
var CollModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        state = ''//or list or dict or whatever
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.items = new Backbone.Collection();
        this.items.on('all', this.setState, this)
    },
    setState: function(){
        this.set(
            'state',
            this.items.reduce(function(state, item){
                /*calculate state*/
            }, '')
        )
    },
    info: function(){
        return this.get('state')
    }
})
```

So you can nest collection-models with similar technic and read their state directly through instance.info() depends on how you calculate it. Your top model state will be updated from cascade updates of underneath models-collections.